# activerecord joins multiple time the same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, parameters, active-record-query

I am doing a simple search looking like this (with 8 different params, but I will copy 2 just for the exemple)

```
 if params[:old] == "on"
   @events = @events.joins(:services).where(services: { name: "old" })
 end

 if params[:big] == "on"
   @events = @events.joins(:services).where(services: { name: "big" })
 end
```

The query works fine when I have only one params "on" and returns my events having the service in the param.

BUT if I have two params "on", even if my event has both services, it's not working anymore.

I've tested it in the console, and I can see that if I do a .joins(:services).where(services: { name: "big" }) on the element that was already joined before, it returns nothing.

I don't understand why.

The first @events (when one param) returns an active record relation with a few events inside.

Why can't I do another .joins on it?

I really don't understand what's wrong in this query and why it becomes empty as soon as it is joined twice.

Thanks a lot

Comment: The reason is because your chaining `where` will generate `AND` clause in Sql query like `WHERE services.name = "old" AND services.name = "big"`, which doesn't exist in your database.

Comment: I think you intention is to to use `OR` not `AND`, correct?

Comment: hmmm I think I do want an AND. If I have only one param, let's say "big" for exemple, I want all the events having "big" as a service. But an event can have many services. So if the user puts two params, "big" and "old", I want all the events having "big" AND "old" as services... Which does exist when I look in my console

Comment: If I do want an AND and if I have an event with both services, it should work no? What am I missing?

Comment: No, it wouldn't work. Because both of your services share the same name variable. You'll do "name == big" AND "name == old", simultaneously and they can't equal both.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. How could I make this work then? What would be the right syntax to put in the second if statement above? 
I want to look for events that have the "big" service, knowing that I already ended up with an Active Record relation of events having the "old" service on the lines before.

Any hint or advice to achieve something like this and make this search work would help a lot! 

Thanks :)

Comment: @Jessicascn I posted the answer below, hope it help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you're using will translate to:

```
SELECT  "events".* FROM "events" INNER JOIN "services" ON "services"."event_id" = "events"."id" WHERE "services"."name" = ? AND "services"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["name", "big"], ["name", "old"], ["LIMIT", 11]]
```

This is why it returns zero record.

Here is the solution I can think of at the moment, not sure if it's the ideal, but yes it works and has been tested.

```
# event.rb
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :services
  has_many :old_services, -> { where(name: 'old') }, class_name: 'Service'
  has_many :big_services, -> { where(name: 'big') }, class_name: 'Service'
end


# service.rb
class Service < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
end
```

And your search method can be written this way:

```
if params[:old] == "on"
  @events = @events.joins(:old_services)
end

if params[:big] == "on"
  @events = @events.joins(:big_services)
end

@events = @events.distinct
# SELECT  DISTINCT "events".* FROM "events" INNER JOIN "services" ON "services"."event_id" = "events"."id" AND "services"."name" = ? INNER JOIN "services" "old_services_events" ON "old_services_events"."event_id" = "events"."id" AND "old_services_events"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["name", "big"], ["name", "old"], ["LIMIT", 11]]
```

Comment: Smart! Thanks a lot.  I've found another solution yesterday, which was to iterate on all my events, do a .pluck(:services) on each of them, and check if the array I end up with in my loop is the same than the one I have in my params. If it is, I push this event in a new array.
It's really unelegant (terrible actually but I could not think of anything else).

I think your solution is better and cleaner! I'll try it

Comment: Works like a charm and even helped me to refactor my code and loop through all services_params :) Thank you

Comment: Ok great to hear that.